# Limitation to passing objects between Android activities

Tags: android, android-activity

As mentioned elsewhere; the way of passing instances between Android activities, is either to make the passing object implement the serializable or parcelable interface. As I see it, this is fine as long your Android app is intented for showing your dog's age and name. Using slightly more advanced objects without using a static reference is problematic.

The object to be passed is using e.g. an external library for its purpose.
For serializing to work all used classes (incl. in the library) needs to declare this interface, otherwise Android will throw a runtime IOException, stating the object could not be serialized (something is not impl. the serializable interface or has no no-arg constructor). So a library recompilation is required for the serializable approach to work I guess.
The Parcel approach requires the object's fields to be written to some output. This output supports custom objects, but then again the passing object (incl. library) needs to implement the serializable interface to work.

What is the solution for passing an instance using an external library?

Answer (score 0):

One of the approaches is to implement Serializer class for each not Serializable type you wants to pass between activities. Here is a simple Serializer interface:

```
public interface Serializer {
    void serialize(Object object, DataOutputStream out);

    Object deserialize(DataInputStream in);
}
```

After that you can use [this](http://docs.yworks.com/graphml/doc/api/org/graphdrawing/graphml/util/Base64.html) or any other Base64 encoder/decoder to convert `DataOutputStream` to `String` or other serializable type. Use for this purposes methods like:

```
private String serializeToString(Object object, Serializer serializer) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream dStream = new DataOutputStream(bStream);

    try {
        serializer.serialize(object, dStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error(e, "Couldn't serialize " + object);
        return null;
    }

    return Base64.encodeToString(bStream.toByteArray(), false);
}

private Object deserializeFromString(String string, Serializer serializer) {
    try {
        return serializer.deserialize(
                new DataInputStream(
                        new ByteArrayInputStream(
                                Base64.decode(string))));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error(e, "Couldn't deserialize [" + string + "]");
        return null;
    }
}
```

After that you can simply pass your object through activities serialized as `String` and simply deserialize it back to your object when you need.